# java selenium xpath to find element with text containing whitespaces

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

I have an element that I want to find by using universal xpath searching for defined text. Problem is that in one of elements text is separated by lots of whitespaces.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-4 control-label" 
    for="demo-hor-inputemail">AP Document
                                            Type *</label>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-8"> 
            <div>
                <ul>
                    <li class="active-result>option</li>
                </ul>
             </div>
         </div>
    </div>
<div>
```

My current working code is something like this:

```
public static void dropdown(String dropdown, String option) {
    drop_down = "//*/label[contains(text(), '" + dropdown + "')]";
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(drop_down + "/following-sibling::div[1]").click;
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(drop_down + 
        "/following-sibling::div/descendant::li[starts-with(text(),'"+ option +"')]")).click;
}
```

I need to find this element by passing text "AP Document Type" as dropdown parameter.

I cannot use just "AP Document" because of having element with that same text.
I have tried passing text with all white spaces but that did not work.
I have tried a few modifiers like this:`[normalize-space(text()) = '"+dropdown+"']`but without luck.

Only way that I have found so far is by passing "Type *" as dropdown variable but I'm seeking for better solution because this case would not work if there were no * in text.

Comment: Our html fragment does not match the xpath which makes it harder to provide an answer. If you already didn't, please read [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @ Luis Muñoz I have read this but I'm not sure what do you mean. In my opinion, my post have minimal content to accurately display what my problem is. Can you please direct me more closely to what part of the original post is not clear enough?

Comment: use `//label[normalize-space()='AP Document Type *']` to select the label.

Comment: :) good that you read it. Your xpath contains a `li` not present in the fragment.

Comment: or `id(//label[normalize-space()='AP Document Type *']/@for)` to get the element associated with the label.

Comment: @ Florent B This xpath worked great. Thank you very much. Do you know a way to normalize space and keep using contains? It would be handy if I could skip some parts of text in the future.

Comment: @Alfodr, `//label[contains(normalize-space(), 'AP Document)']/@for`

Comment: @Andersson That worked. I have now exactly what I need.

Comment: Are you able to answer and accept your answer? It looks quite useful, people would like to find this in the future.

Comment: @Paul Hicks Oh, I'll do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Florent B. and Andersson, I found a solution.

`"//label[contains(normalize-space(), '" + dropdown + "')]"`  works great.

Comment: Isn't `//*/` exactly the same as `//`?

Comment: @Paul Hicks You are right. Changing //*/label to //label did not make any difference. Thanks.